# Expanding object attributes in Double-quoted Powershell strings

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell, and I'm facing a problem expanding the value of an object attribute in a double-quoted String. Can somebody please explain this to me:
I would expect you to write "$(var.attr)", but this fails, here's a sample describing the problem:

```
     PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $c = Get-Volume -DriveLetter 'C'
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $c.Size
126696288256
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> "$c.size"
MSFT_Volume (ObjectId = "{1}\\KEPPLAPTOP3\root/Microsoft/Windows...).size
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> "$(c.size)"
c.size : The term 'c.size' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ "$(c.size)"
+    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c.size:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

As you can see, Ican easily display the Size attribute of the $c object, when not in a double-quoted string, when I try expanding without parenthesis, it only expands the object, but when I include the object.attr in parenthesis, it cannot recognize the expression.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like it is looking for an object named "c.size" rather than an object named "c" with a method call of ".size".

Comment: Use `$($c.size)` inside `"`s. See [Powershell: Everything you wanted to know about variable substitution in strings](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/)

Comment: Thanks DavidPostil, I think, that should have been an answer, rather than a comment.